# Installing application on laptop without HDD using live Windows DVD

Tags: windows, windows-7, boot, livecd

I have an old Laptop which:

- its hard disk is damaged
- I cannot boot it by bootable USB flash
- I can boot it by live windows 7 DVD

So I boot it using live windows 7 DVD.

Now I want to install [MIT Scratch offline editor](https://scratch.mit.edu/download) after starting `Windows`. But on installing it says the `X:\` (which stores `program files` directory) has not enough space.

I tried to change the default installation directory to a directory in USB flash by editing `regedit`, as it is described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-you-change-the-default-installation/73450b25-d794-4f18-9add-75253b893343), without `restarting` the OS; but the problem remained.

Comment: There is a high likelihood of that application not even support Windows 7 let alone attempting to configure it within a "live Windows 7" environment.

Comment: @Ramhound No, It is compatible with `Windows 7`; because I installed that.

Answer (score 0):

i think that when you install an program, the program always write some data in windows or programfiles, i guess that's why you get that error.
maybe you can try to first boot an commandprompt trough the windows dvd, and from there on you try to start windows from usb drive?

good luck

Comment: You state, "I boot it using live windows 7 DVD." How can you **WRITE** to the DVD?? See if you can figure out how to boot from USB -- try Linux, e.g., Ubuntu Live CD, which is more forgiving on install than Windows.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Unfortunately Scratch does not support Linux.